Rootless docker permission error on nfs drive
On my host, I mounted a nfs to the users home directory (~/docker_volumes) via fstab 192.168.2.102:/volume1/nuc_data/user1/docker_volumes /home/user1/docker_volumes nfs defaults,async 0 0 The user can access it without any problems.
When I run some (not all) rootless docker containers with a volume referencing something on ~/docker_volumes they have permission errors, in their logs. This happens with Gitlab for example.
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.domain.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
        external_url 'https://gitlab.domain.com'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '2222:2222'
    volumes:
      - '/home/user1/docker_volumes/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/home/user1/docker_volumes/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/home/user1/docker_volumes/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    shm_size: '256m'

Part from the log:
================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/var/opt/gitlab/.gitconfig]'
    ================================================================================
    
    Errno::EPERM
    ------------
    Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /var/opt/gitlab/.gitconfig

When I change it to use "normal" folder instead of those on the nfs it works fine.
It also works on the nfs when running it a privileged container.
The permissions and ownership look exactly the same on the nfs and the local alternative where it works, as far as I can tell.
Does anyone know what causes this and how it can be fixed?
